# Implement an if/else condition in x86 assembly that selects one of two constants (that differ by 1)

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization

Can someone help me translate this pseudocode into x86 assembly?

```
if (eax > ebx)  
    mov dl, 5;  
else  
    mov dl, 6;
```

Answer (score 4):

the simple version:

```
CMP EAX,EBX
JG L1
MOV DL,6
JMP L2
L1:
MOV DL,5
L2:
```

the optimized version:

```
CMP EAX,EBX ; dl = (eax > ebx) ? 5 : 6
SETLE DL
ADD DL,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use [conditional move](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc). You didn't specify whether the comparison is signed or unsigned but in case it's signed:

```
cmp    eax, ebx
cmovg  dl, 5
cmovle dl, 6
```

See also [Unpredictable Conditional Branches on 32-Bit Intel® Architecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20091012115037/http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/unpredictable-conditional-branches-on-32-bit-intel-architecture)

Comment: `cmov` doesn't allow immediate source operands, or 8-bit operand-size.  (Only 16/32/64).  The 16 different condition-code predicates take enough coding space with just one range of opcodes.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc

Comment: yes you're right. Didn't know cmovcc is so limited like that

Comment: Also, even if this did work, there's no reason to make the first one a `cmov` instead of `mov`.  That introduces a false dependency on the old value (and on the cmp result) for no benefit, and costs an extra uop on Intel before Broadwell (where cmov is 2 uops).  It's not like ARM predicated instructions; `cmov` is just an ALU select with 2 integer inputs + 1 flag input.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing an unsigned comparison, the compare result goes into the carry flag.  "Below" is the same condition as carry-set (e.g. `a-b` produces a carry-out, so `a` was strictly below `b`, not equal or above).  Notice that [`jb` is the same opcode as `jc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc), just different mnemonics for different semantic meanings of the same flag condition.

Unlike most flags, there are special instructions that use the carry flag, like `adc` and `sbb`, letting us add the carry flag to another register.

```
cmp  ebx, eax    ; set CF if   ebx  <unsigned  eax
mov  dl, 6                   ; optionally mov edx,5 to avoid false dependencies
sbb  dl, 0       ; 6 - (eax > ebx)

;; dl = eax > ebx ? 5 : 6
```

The logic can be tricky to figure out: `cmp` in the other order will reverse the sense of the comparison, and you can `mov dl,5` / `adc dl,0` instead of sbb to do other unsigned conditions like <=.

In this case, `ebx - eax` (done by CMP) sets CF if `ebx < eax`  i.e. `CF = eax > ebx`.  So we need to subtract CF from 6.

However, for an 8-bit register that you need to initialize, setcc + add may be a better choice: it's fewer uops on more CPUs.  `adc reg,0` is 2 uops on Intel P6-family.  `adc reg,imm8` is 2 uops on Intel SnB through Haswell as well, for non-zero imm8.  But setcc is only 1 uop and efficient, but only available with an 8-bit destination.  (For wider outputs you normally want to xor-zero a wider register before the flag-setting operation which costs you an extra uop.)

But in this version, the `mov dl,5` can execute without waiting for the `cmp`, so if the cmp inputs were on the critical path for latency, this only has an `adc` after them.  That's only 1 uop on AMD and Intel SnB-family (because we used an immediate operand of 0.)  So the critical-path latency from EAX or EBX to the result in DL is only 2 cycles, cmp + adc.  vs. 3 cycles for cmp/setcc/add.

See also https://agner.org/optimize/ for more uop-count / latency info.

Also beware partial-register effects: [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to use MASM32, where such if/else constructs are legal...