# Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Disassembling `write(1,"hi",3)` on linux, built with `gcc -s -nostdlib -nostartfiles -O3` results in:

```
ba03000000     mov edx, 3 ; thanks for the correction jester!
bf01000000     mov edi, 1
31c0           xor eax, eax
e9d8ffffff     jmp loc.imp.write
```

I'm not into compiler development but since every value moved into these registers are constant and known compile-time, I'm curious why doesn't gcc uses `dl`, `dil`, and `al` instead.
Some may argue that this feature won't make any difference in performance but there's a big difference in executable size between `mov $1, %rax => b801000000` and `mov $1, %al => b001` when we are talking about thousands of register accesses in a program. Not only small size if part of a software's elegance, it does have effect on performance.

Can someone explain why did "GCC decide" that it doesn't matter?

Comment: if you only load partial registers the rest will contain random garbage and the callee will use the whole register (as appropriate for the data type). Also it causes partial register stalls. Note that writing the low 32 bits will however zero the top 32 bits automatically. PS: you disassembled wrong, all of those instructions are actually 32 bit (no rex prefix).

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with GCC, every C compiler is required to do this.  Google "C integer promotion" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant Does Integer promotion work for function arguments of prototyped functions? As far I can tell from the standard only the [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) apply for function calls. Quoting: "*The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
argument expressions [ndr: the default arg promotions of above], to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the
shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses*"

Comment: @MargaretBloom The value passed an argument is converted by assignment to the type of argument. See paragraph 7. Either way this means that the constants `3` and `1`, which are already `signed int`, remain as `signed int`.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes, but does assignment performs integer promotion? From my understanding, the answer seems to be no.

Comment: @MargaretBloom No, but I don't think quibbling about where Hans Passant was using the correct terminology is all that helpful here. I should correct my last comment though, the constant `3` will either remain as `signed int` or be converted to `size_t` depending on whether there's a prototype.

Comment: @RossRidge Of course, that was just total nitpicking in this context. I've asked because I stumbled on [this weird case](https://godbolt.org/g/CYsYIo) and I'm considering if it's worth asking about.

Comment: @MargaretBloom For what its worth the `xor eax, eax` indicates that the call was made without a prototype in scope. It doesn't know whether the function is varargs or not, so it sets AL to 0 indicate 0 arguments passed in SSE registers. Your weird case is really an ABI question, the "as if" rule allows either implementation so long as both ends agree on it.

Comment: @RossRidge That's a good point.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, GCC generally avoids writing to partial registers, unless optimizing for size (`-Os`) instead of purely speed (`-O3`).  Some cases require writing at least the 32-bit register for correctness, so a better example would be something like:

`char foo(char *p) { return *p; }` compiles to `movzx eax, byte ptr [rdi]`
instead of `mov al, [rdi]`.   https://godbolt.org/z/4ca9cTG9j

But GCC doesn't always avoid partial registers, sometimes even causing partial-register stalls https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15533

---

Writing partial registers entails a performance penalty on many x86 processors because they are renamed into different physical registers from their whole counterpart when written.  (For more about register renaming enabling out-of-order execution, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction)).

But when an instruction reads the whole register, the CPU has to detect the fact that it doesn't have the correct architectural register value available in a single physical register.  (This happens in the issue/rename stage, as the CPU prepares to send the uop into the out-of-order scheduler.)

It's called a *partial register stall*. [Agner Fog's microarchitecture manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) explains it pretty well:

> **6.8 Partial register stalls**  (PPro/PII/PIII and early Pentium-M)

> Partial register stall is a problem that occurs when we write to part of a 32-bit register and later read from the whole register or a bigger part of it.
> Example:

```
; Example 6.10a. Partial register stall
mov al, byte ptr [mem8]
mov ebx, eax ; Partial register stall
```

> **This gives a delay of 5 - 6 clocks**. The reason is that a temporary register has been
> assigned to `AL` to make it independent of `AH`. The execution unit has to wait until the write to `AL` has retired before it is possible to combine the value from `AL` with the value of the rest of
> `EAX`.

**Behaviour in different CPUs**:

- Intel early P6 family: see above: stall for 5-6 clocks until the partial writes retire.
- Intel Pentium-M (model D) / Core2 / Nehalem: stall for 2-3 cycles while inserting a merging uop.  (see [this Q&A for a microbenchmark writing AX and reading EAX with or without xor-zeroing first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092829/any-way-to-move-2-bytes-in-32-bit-x86-using-mov-without-causing-a-mode-switch-or))
- Intel Sandybridge: insert a merging uop for low8/low16 (AL/AX) without stalling, or for AH/BH/CH/DH while stalling for 1 cycle.
- Intel IvyBridge (maybe), but definitely Haswell / Skylake: AL/AX aren't renamed, but AH still is:
  [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).
- **All other x86 CPUs**: Intel Pentium4, Atom / Silvermont / Knight's Landing. All AMD (and Via, etc): partial registers are never renamed.  Writing a partial register merges into the full register, making the write depend on the old value of the full register as an input.

Without partial-register renaming, the input dependency for the write is a *false* dependency if you never read the full register.  This limits instruction-level parallelism because reusing an 8 or 16-bit register for something else is not actually independent from the CPU's point of view (16-bit code can access 32-bit registers, so it has to maintain correct values in the upper halves).  And also, it makes AL and AH not independent.  When Intel designed P6-family (PPro released in 1993), 16-bit code was still common, so partial-register renaming was an important feature to make existing machine code run faster.  (In practice, many binaries don't get recompiled for new CPUs.)

That's why compilers mostly avoid *writing* partial registers.  They use `movzx` / `movsx` whenever possible to zero- or sign-extend narrow values to a full register to avoid partial-register false dependencies (AMD) or stalls (Intel P6-family).  Thus most modern machine code doesn't benefit much from partial-register renaming, which is why recent Intel CPUs are simplifying their partial-register renaming logic.

[As @BeeOnRope's answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers/42868730#42868730), compilers still *read* partial registers, because that's not a problem.  (Reading AH/BH/CH/DH can add an extra cycle of latency on Haswell/Skylake, though, see the earlier link about partial registers on recent members of Sandybridge-family.)

---

**Also note** that [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) takes arguments that, for an x86-64 typically configured GCC, need whole 32-bit and 64-bit registers so it couldn't simply be assembled into `mov dl, 3`. The size is determined by the *type* of the data, not the *value* of the data.

Only 32-bit register writes implicitly zero-extend to the full 64-bit; writing 8 and 16-bit partial registers leave the upper bytes unchanged.  (This makes it tricky for hardware to handle efficiently, [which is why AMD64 didn't follow that pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).)

Finally, in certain contexts, C has [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) to be aware of, <s>though this is not the case</s>.
Actually, as [RossRidge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers?noredirect=1#comment70355979_41573502) pointed out, the call was probably made without a visible prototype.

---

Your disassembly is misleading, as @Jester pointed out.
For example `mov rdx, 3` is actually `mov edx, 3`, although both have the same effect—that is, to put 3 in the whole `rdx`.
This is true because an immediate value of 3 doesn't require sign-extension and a `MOV r32, imm32` implicitly clears the upper 32 bits of the register.

Comment: "a temporary register has been assigned to AL to make it independent of AH". Why assign a "new" register for it, AL isn't physically a "subset" of EAX? Why does it have to be separated from EAX?

Comment: To make more instructions execute in parallel. It's called [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming), the Agner Fog manual I linked has more in-depth material than the Wikipedia article. Intel Optimisation manuals also cover this topic.

Comment: The above quotation from Agner Fog is for Netburst (Pentium 4). The quoted delay of 5 - 6 clocks is much better on later microarchitectures. For example from Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge, *The Ivy Bridge inserts an extra μop only in the case where a high 8-bit register (AH, BH, CH, DH) has been modified*

Comment: Thanks @Olsonist, it is worth mentioning. If you don't mind I'll quote your comment in the answer.

Comment: Yes, the simple answer has nothing to do with register stalls (it is easy to find examples of compilers reading and writing the partial registers even at `-O2` and `-O3`), but that the x86 and x86-64 _requires_ that arguments smaller than 32-bits are zero or sign extended when passing them to functions. Regardless of what the prototype is, and even if there is no prototype in scope (the ABI still applies then, with some "default" function signature based on the shape of the call). Interestingly, the high 32-bits [can](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40475902) contain garbage, but not bits 8 to 32.

Comment: @BeeOnRope What an interesting question you asked! I had the very same question a bit ago, when I posted [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers/41574531?noredirect=1#comment70355715_41573502) above.

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't clicked on it! I wrote an answer below that covers some of the nuances, but it links to two other questions that cover it in a lot of details. What I just discovered while playing around with this question though is that apparently `icc` doesn't respect the defacto rules, so actually `icc` and `clang` are incompatible on Linux and OSX too (I guess `icc` exists on OSX)? The short version is that while both `clang` and `gcc` respect the "zero extend rule", only `clang` _relies_ on it, as your example shows. `gcc` zero extends, but doesn't use that fact to optimize...

Comment: BTW, my claim above is a bit too strong, I wrote it before I did the remaining research and found out that it is a bit of a weaker "defacto" standard than I thought, with `icc` not adhering and some debate about what the right thing to do is. The key to the OPs question though is that `gcc` does follow the extension-to-32-bits rule.

Comment: I fixed several things that were wrong (the quote is for early P6, not Netburst), and added a table of how different CPUs handle partial registers.  Anyway, I wanted to link to a good answer about partial registers in general, and now this is one, IMO :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much Peter! I really appreciate it

Comment: @PeterCordes is there any information on how expensive the merging uop for partial registers on Haswell and newer is? Does it only show up as 1 uop in ROB (so unless ROB bottleneck no cost) or can it cause bottlenecks elsewhere.

Comment: @Noah: As discussed in [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139), the only merging on HSW and later is high-8, and it seems that a high-8 merging uop has to issue in a cycle by itself (like Intel documents for SnB, IIRC). So it costs more front-end bandwidth than you'd expect, but otherwise AFAIK it's just 1 uop for the ROB (and probably RS, I forget if it needs a back-end port).  I haven't done a lot of experiments with it.

Comment: @Noah: Oh, also IIRC, a loop that needs a high-8 merge was supposed to not run from the LSD, before Intel disabled SKL's LSD entirely (because of a correctness bug involving this somehow).  Maybe still a thing on HSW or ICL.

Answer (score 6):

All three of the earlier answers are wrong in different ways.

The accepted answer by Margaret Bloom implies that partial register stalls are to blame. Partial register stalls are a real thing, but are unlikely to be relevant to GCC's decision here.

If GCC replaced `mov edx,3` by `mov dl,3`, then the code would just be wrong, because writes to byte registers (unlike writes to dword registers) don't zero the rest of the register. The parameter in `rdx` is of type `size_t`, which is 64 bits, so the callee will read the full register, which will contain garbage in bits 8 to 63. Partial register stalls are purely a performance issue; it doesn't matter how fast the code runs if it's wrong.

That bug could be fixed by inserting `xor edx,edx` before `mov dl,3`. With that fix, there is no partial register stall, because zeroing a full register with `xor` or `sub` and then writing to the low byte is special-cased in all CPUs that have the stalling problem. So partial register stalls are still irrelevant with the fix.

The only situation where partial register stalls would become relevant is if GCC happened to know that the register was zero, but it wasn't zeroed by one of the special-cased instructions. For example, if this syscall was preceded by

```
loop:
  ...
  dec edx
  jnz loop
```

then GCC could deduce that `rdx` was zero at the point where it wants to put 3 in it, and `mov dl,3` would be correct – but it would be a bad idea in general because it could cause a partial-register stall. (Here, it wouldn't matter because syscalls are so slow anyway, but I don't think GCC has a "slow function that there's no need to speed-optimize calls to" attribute in its internal type system.)

---

Why doesn't GCC emit `xor` followed by a byte move, if not because of partial register stalls? I don't know but I can speculate.

It only saves space when initializing `r0` through `r3`, and even then it only saves one byte. It increases the number of instructions, which has its own costs (the instruction decoders are frequently a bottleneck). It also clobbers the flags unlike the standard `mov`, which means it isn't a drop-in replacement. GCC would have to track a separate flag-clobbering register initialization sequence, which in most cases (11/15 of possible destination registers) would be unambiguously less efficient.

If you're aggressively optimizing for size, you can do `push 3` followed by `pop rdx`, which saves 2 bytes regardless of the destination register, and doesn't clobber the flags. But it is probably much slower because it writes to memory and has a false read-write dependence on `rsp`, and the space savings seem unlikely to be worth it. (It also modifies the [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)), so it isn't a drop-in replacement either.)

---

supercat's answer says

> Processor cores often include logic to execute multiple 32-bit or 64-bit instructions simultaneously, but may not include logic to execute an 8-bit operation simultaneously with anything else. Consequently, while using 8-bit operations on the 8088 when possible was a useful optimization on the 8088, it can actually be a significant performance drain on newer processors.

Modern optimizing compilers actually use 8-bit GPRs quite a lot. (They use 16-bit GPRs relatively rarely, but I think that's because 16-bit quantities are uncommon in modern code.) 8-bit and 16-bit operations are at least as fast as 32-bit and 64-bit operations at most execution stages, and some are faster.

I previously wrote here "As far as I know, 8-bit operations are as fast as, or faster than, 32/64-bit operations on absolutely every 32/64 bit x86/x64 processor ever made." But I was wrong. Quite a few superscalar x86/x64 processors merge 8- and 16-bit destinations into the full register on every write, which means that write-only instructions like `mov` have a false read dependency when the destination is 8/16 bits which doesn't exist when it's 32/64 bits. False dependency chains can slow execution if you don't clear the register before every move (or during, using something like `movzx`). Newer processors have this problem even though the earliest superscalar processors (Pentium Pro/II/III) didn't have it. In spite of that, modern optimizing compilers do use the smaller registers in my experience.

---

BeeOnRope's answer says

> The short answer *for your particular case*, is because gcc always sign or zero-extends arguments to 32-bits when calling a C ABI function.

But this function has no parameters shorter than 32 bits in the first place. File descriptors are exactly 32 bits long, and `size_t` is exactly 64 bits long. It doesn't matter that many of those bits are often zero. They aren't variable-length integers that are encoded in 1 byte if they're small. It would only be correct to use `mov dl,3`, with the rest of `rdx` possibly being nonzero, for a parameter if there was no integer promotion requirement in the ABI *and* the actual parameter type was `char` or some other 8-bit type.

Comment: The question chose a bad example (where at least 32-bit registers are necessary for both args).  Margaret is answering the also-interesting general case about why GCC uses `movzx eax, byte ptr [rdi]` to implement `char foo(char *p) { return *p; }` and similar cases like that.  Or `char bar(){ return 1; }` https://godbolt.org/z/4ca9cTG9j shows that at -Os (optimize for size), GCC *does* just write AL instead of extending into EAX.  (And that clang just writes AL, cavalierly risking partial-register false dependencies; the caller can be assumed not to read EAX.)

Comment: Re: the 3-byte push/pop: On modern CPUs, the "[stack engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture)" that handles RSP updates by stack instructions in the front-end, during issue/rename, handles the read-write dependence on rsp with zero latency.  (But later explicit uses of RSP would then need a stack-sync uop on Intel CPUs).  `clang -Oz` optimizes for size without caring about speed, and actually does use push/pop.

Comment: If you need multiple nearby constants, 3-byte `lea edx, [rax+1]` or w/e can be good.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132985).  Interesting idea about xor-zero and `mov dl, 3`, though, for 4 bytes.  You're right that being 2 instructions and 2 uops in the front-end might be a bottleneck, for either decode or issue.  And takes more space in the uop cache.  Also takes more space in the ROB, limiting how far ahead the CPU can see to find ILP for out-of-order exec.

Comment: *8-bit operations are as fast as, or faster than, 32/64-bit operations on absolutely every 32/64 bit x86/x64 processor ever made* - For the ALU part yes, I think that's true.  But using 8-bit operand-size means *writing* partial registers, which means false dependencies on some CPUs.  This can make `mov al, cl` slower  than `mov eax, ecx` in both throughput and even latency (mov elimination only works on 32 and 64-bit mov, or on Intel, on movzx 8->32 bit).  e.g. IvyBridge can do 4/clock 32-bit mov (no back-end ALU port needed), but only 3/clock 8-bit mov even if you use different regs.

Comment: For 2-input operations like `add` that isn't a concern, you already need to read-modify the destination so the output dependency isn't false.  Things like xor-zeroing are slower on 8-bit registers, though, since they can't be eliminated.  See [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139). And also GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15533 (especially my comment at the end - GCC since 4.4 causes a partial reg stall with `xor al,al` / read EAX)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for all the comments. I didn't realize many processors have false dependencies in 8/16 bit writes. I edited the answer.

Comment: Cheers.  Definitely some good points in this answer, happy to help out with extra details.

Comment: BTW, Margaret's answer *did* mention the fact that 32-bit register writes were requires in the question's example for correctness, but only in a section at the bottom.  I added a useful example to the top of the answer.  Your answer is still correct that avoiding partial register stalls isn't the issue *here* (or for the example I added), although it would be for setting up a `char` function arg: the function might well copy the whole 32-bit or 64-bit register even if only the low byte has the function arg.

Comment: 'I don't think GCC has a "slow function that there's no need to speed-optimize calls to" attribute in its internal type system' there is hotness tracking.  It happens at least with `__attribute__((cold))` on functions, `__builtin_expect` on branches, and dynamic information collected from PGO.

Answer (score -1):

On something like the original IBM PC, if AH was known to contain 0 and it was necessary to load AX with a value like 0x34, using "MOV AL,34h" would generally take 8 cycles rather than the 12 required for "MOV AX,0034h"--a pretty big speed improvement (either instruction could execute in 2 cycles if pre-fetched, but in practice the 8088 spends most of its time waiting for instructions to be fetched at a cost of four cycles per byte).  On the processors used in today's general-purpose computers, however, the time required to fetch code is generally not a significant factor in overall execution speed, and code size is normally not a particular concern.

Further, processor vendors try to maximize the performance of the kinds of code people are likely to run, and 8-bit load instructions aren't likely to be used nearly as often nowadays as 32-bit load instructions.  Processor cores often include logic to execute multiple 32-bit or 64-bit instructions simultaneously, but may not include logic to execute an 8-bit operation simultaneously with anything else.  Consequently, while using 8-bit operations on the 8088 when possible was a useful optimization on the 8088, it can actually be a significant performance drain on newer processors.

Comment: *but may not include logic to execute an 8-bit operation simultaneously with anything else* I'm not aware of any x86 CPUs where that's the case.  The real problem for modern compilers is writing partial registers, which various microarchitectures handle different ways.  (These days mainly by merging on the spot, so `mov al, whatever` has a false dependency on the old value of RAX.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Perhaps I didn't phrase things well, since a false dependency wouldn't necessarily preclude simultaneous operation with unrelated registers, but it's still limits a processor's ability to overlap operations that should be able to overlap.  My main point was that if the upper portion of RAX is known to be zero, the fact that MOV AL,12h is smaller than MOV EAX,12h isn't as likely to improve speed so much as the false dependency issues would be to make it slower.